# knockout.js - data-bind attr default values

Tags: html, knockout.js

I have a simple html element with an `attr` binding:

```
<img src="defaultImage.png" alt="default" data-bind="attr: {src: imgUrl, alt: imgAlt}" />
```

What I'd like to do is have a custom extender to take the default value for `src` and `alt` and automatically initialize them into the Knockout observables.

There are plenty of examples for doing this for a value or text binding but none for arbitrary `attr` bindings.

Is this possible?

Comment: Have you tried any approach yet? It's not entirely clear what you're after, possibly because the question is very broad as there are many ways to accomplish this. ("Is this possible?", the answer, without offense, is "Yes"; as it stands the post reads more like a disguised to-do than as a question)

Answer (score 1):

This is dirty, but helps if you don't have a lot of places where it should be written:

```
<img src="defaultImage.png" alt="default" data-bind="attr: { src: imgUrl() || 'defaultUrl', alt: imgAlt() || 'defaultAlt' }" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same requirement - thought this example is just only for the *img tag* attribute, it could be easily extended for all attributes:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.src = {
    update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        ko.bindingHandlers.attr.update(element, function () {
            return {src: valueAccessor()};
        });
    }
};
```

Usage:

```
<img data-bind="src: imgUrl" />
```

The custom binding above will follow the classic way, first you will initialize the observable, then the image src attribute is updated - this means, the img src will take also the default initialization value of the knockout observable.

If you need the reverse way, you can use the custom binding init callback:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.src = {
  init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
    var value = valueAccessor();
    value(element.src);
  },
  update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
    ko.bindingHandlers.attr.update(element, function() {
      return {
        src: valueAccessor()
      };
    });
  }
};
```

The usage in markup is the same, but the effect at initialization is inverted.

Here is a Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/CwI6KGirOkb3XpgS0Dj8?p=preview